# Stepwise regression in R – Critical p-value

Tags: r, regression, p-value, stepwise-regression

What is the critical p-value used by the `step()` function in R for stepwise regression? I assume it is 0.15, but is my assumption correct? How can I change the critical p-value?

Comment: R's 'step' function is AIC based.

Comment: It is best not to use stepwise model selection routines at all. To understand why, it may help you to read my answer here: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290).

Comment: Further to @MichaelMayer's comment: the `Description` part of the help page to `?step` says, in its entirety: *Select a formula-based model by AIC.*

Answer (score 29):

As I explained in my comment on your other question, `step` uses AIC rather than p-values.

However, for a *single* variable at a time, AIC *does* correspond to using a p-value of 0.15 (or to be more precise, 0.1573):

Consider comparing two models, which differ by a single variable. Call the models $\cal{M}_0$ (smaller model) and $\cal{M}_1$ (larger model), and let their AIC's be $\text{AIC}_0$ and $\text{AIC}_1$ respectively.

Using the AIC criterion, you'd use the larger model if $\text{AIC}_1<\text{AIC}_0$. This will be the case if $-2\log\cal{L_0}-(-2\log\cal{L_1})>2$.

But this is simply the statistic in a likelihood ratio test. From Wilks' theorem, we'll reject the null if the statistic exceeds the upper $\alpha$ quantile of a $\chi^2_1$. So if we use a hypothesis test to choose between the smaller model and the larger, we choose the larger model when $-2\log\cal{L_0}-(-2\log\cal{L_1})>C_\alpha$.

Now $2$ lies at the 84.27 percentile of a $\chi^2_1$. Hence, if we choose the larger model when it has smaller AIC, this corresponds to rejecting the null hypothesis for a test of the additional term with a p-value of $1-0.843=0.157$, or $15.7\%$

---

So how do you modify it?

Easy. Change the `k` parameter in `step` from 2 to something else. You want 10% instead? Make it 2.7:

```
qchisq(0.10,1,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 2.705543
```

You want 2.5%? Set `k=5`:

```
qchisq(0.025,1,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 5.023886
```

and so on.

---

However, even though that solves your question, I advise you to pay close attention to Frank Harrell's answer on your other question, and to search out responses from a great many statisticians on other questions relating to stepwise regression here, which advice tends to be very consistently to avoid stepwise procedures in general.

Comment: Nice explanation. Do you know whether this would hold approximately true for the p-values of ordinary regression t-tests?

Comment: Sorry Ben, I'm not 100% sure what "this" refers to. Are you saying "could I use the above approach where you showed how to do tests at 10% and 2.5% to do 5% tests with?" If so the answer is "obviously, yes"... but the final sentence -- which points out that even though you *look* like you're doing tests at some nominal level, the *actual* type I error rates are nothing like their nominal values. In other words, you can compute a value to use, and it should be equivalent to doing stepwise set to $\alpha=0.05$ ... but the actual significance level still won't be 5%. That's only one of ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... a slew of serious problems with stepwise. Others include biased estimates and standard errors that are far too small.

Comment: Momentarily putting aside problems with stepwise model selection, I'm interested in generalizing the smaller AIC => .1573 p-value rule. The Likelihood Ratio p-value you describe is fine, but in routines like R's lm, estimate/std.err is being compared to a t-distribution. This is a different test, and I was wondering if your .1573 result might hold approximately.

Comment: [Russ Lenth's answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/109422/32036) to my (only) question seems to arrive at the same number: "$2\Phi(-\sqrt{2}) \approx .1573$ (here, $\Phi$ denotes the $N(0,1)$ cdf)." As I'm out of my league on these topics, I can't help wondering...Coincidence? Useful?

Comment: Ben: yes, the .1573 is asymptotic (based on normal; it will only be approximately correct). I think you could compute the corresponding p-value to stepAIC for a $t$, since it will depend only on the degrees of freedom in your problem (e.g. I think it's 0.1579 for 200 df); as a result you should be able to back out the desired $k$. @Nick That's most interesting. On a first glance I don't think there's a direct connection between the calculations -- they're computing the same quantity, but for different reasons.

Answer (score 4):

As said above, the `step` function in R is based on AIC criteria. But I guess by p-value you mean alpha to enter and alpha to leave. What you can do is to use the function `stepwise` written by Paul Rubin and available [here](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.ca/2011/02/stepwise-regression-in-r.html). As you can see you have the arguments of alpha.to.enter and alpha.to.leave that you can change. Note that this function uses the F-test or equivalently t-test to select the models. Moreover, it can handle not only stepwise regression but also forward selection and backward elimination as well if you properly define the arguments.