# Saving each step of Backward selection in R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, model

I'm trying to recreate Leo Breiman's work http://www.stat.washington.edu/courses/stat527/s13/readings/BreimanSpector_1992.pdf and I'm experiencing some major difficulties in R.

I've made it that far that I have a function producing random samples from multivariate normal distribution with zero mu vector and covariance matrix same as in the paper.

If I understand the paper correctly, I should make a random sample (checked), apply one of the 4 models H1-H4 to get the real values y (checked) and then apply LOOCV, K Fold, or Bootstrap to fit the data and compare the hat ys with the real ones. Though I'm not very experienced, I think I'm capable to construct all of this.

What I'm having major difficulties with is that I can't seem to find any fuction that would allow me to repeat the process in the paragraph above, store the result, and then repeat it again with -1 variables (the excluded variable can be excluded based on any criteria).

I've experimented with step(), stepAIC(), leaps(), regsubsets() and nothing gave me the slightest hint of what I need. However, there's a 100% chance I'm using them wrong. Can you please advise?

Thanks to everyone.
Ondra

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "store the result". Which result do you wish to store?

As far as refitting, R has a function `update` that will refit a model with changed inputs.

Alternatively you might looking for functions like `drop1` (and `add1`).

Functions like `leaps` are designed to make their own way through many models, you seem to want to implement the individual stages of moving between adjacent models, and refitting.

Comment: Well, I'd like to fit the model with let's say 40 variables, calculate Model Error, save the Model Error, drop the least significant explanatory variable, repeat.

Comment: I should take this chance to mention the repeated warnings here on CrossValidated against stepwise model selection.

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97257/stepwise-regression-in-r-critical-p-value) for a discussion of how to make `step` work on single-variable-at-a-time significance. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/805) for a list of problems with what you want to do.

Comment: About the stepwise, I know, I've stumbled upon a couple of threads mentioning this; however, I'm struggling with basics.
Once I get the model working, I might start experiencing with other methods as well. Now I just need any seemingly justifiable variable deletion technique to get the whole thing going. Nevertheless, I want to thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm happy to help you learn how to do it. What remains unanswered?

Comment: not sure:) right now im using: 'a<-step(fit,scope= list(lower=~1, upper=~.),direction=c("backward"),steps=1)' which works fine and drops the variable with the lowest AIC. 

However,I've got 40 of them and I'd like to use a loop to go from 40 to constant. I was thinking either **for** or **while** loop.

Though **while** would be probably better, i know only **for** loop.I'm not sure if it even matters. I could just store all the AICs to a new object and say which model has the lowest. Yet, I've been advised twice to use **while**

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you're looping a known number of times I don't see why it would matter which you used.

Comment: However, why not make step larger and use `keep`?

Comment: Is keep a part of some package? it's hard to google "keep" :( 

Nevertheless, this is how far I've got (and it's not working the way I intended):
'i<-1
fit<-lm(yn~.,data=training1)
a[i]<-AIC(fit)
while (a[i]>a[i+1]){
  i<-i+1
    c<-step(fit,scope= list(lower=~1, upper=~.),direction=c("backward"),steps=1)
  newfit<-lm(c,data=training1)
  a[i+1]<-AIC(newfit)
  }'
The point was to fit the first model and compute the AIC. Then in the **while** loop, it was supposed to drop 1 if the condition that the AIC of the new model is lower. And repeat till the end. 

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: Tried the same with **for** and I might be missing something crucial.

i<-1
fit<-lm(yn~.,data=training1)
a[i]<-AIC(fit)

for (i in 40){ 
  fit<-lm(yn~.,data=training1)
  c<-step(fit,scope= list(lower=~1, upper=~.),direction=c("backward"),steps=1)
  fit<-lm(c,data=training1)
  a[i]<-AIC(fit)
  i<-i+1  
}

What I think it does is that for the first time it takes the original fit, then drops 1 variable and recreates the old fit to new one and repeats. However, calling a[i] is a mess. So, again, any input is welcome :) Thank you.

Comment: Ondra, read the help on `step` of which `keep` is an argument.

Comment: Questions of the form "how do I make this code work" are a better fit for stackoverflow. You need to read the help on `for` (`?"for"` - don't leave out the quotes). I believe `step` will do the whole thing in one go.