# stepwise logistic regression non significative variables(high p-values)

Tags: r, p-value, stepwise-regression

i am doing stepwise for logistic regression then the p-values of all variables selected were high then 0.05. According to this publication 
[Stepwise regression in R – Critical p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97257/stepwise-regression-in-r-critical-p-value)
I changed the code to the following

```
step(glm(y~.,data=mydat,family="binomial"),direction="both",k=9)
 9.22952=qchisq(0.05,3.84,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

but the problem persist mean that i have the following p-values

```
0.21
0.19
```

What shall i do?  Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: qchisq(0.05, 1, lower.tail = FALSE) does not equal 9 in my version of R. I suppose it is pointless telling you that the post you link to does say this (stepwise modelling) is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: yes mdewey you are right i modified the post,
why stepwise modelling is a bad idea ?

Comment: I still think your call of qchisq is wrong.

Comment: mdewey this is what i found in the link above !

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a more serious issue here than the use of stepwise regression

> but the use is a must for me ! how can i get 0.05 p values means significant variables using stepwise ?

Science *is not* a quest for `p < 0.05`.  Science *is* a quest for discovering repeatable and understandable patterns in our world.  If you go into research looking for `p < 0.05`, you will find it with enough effort.  Unfortunately, to do so, you sell out the soul of true science, and your results will no longer be scientific.

The idea between the `p < 0.05` threshold is to guarantee that at most $5\%$ of research findings are false positives.  But this guarantee makes a lot of assumptions about the honesty and integrity of the scientists using the statistical tools.  Dredging your data to find `p < 0.05` is about the worst thing you can do, it annihilates all of the guarantees the statistical framework is supposed to provide.

So yes, we could tell you how to torture your data until you get the magical `p < 0.05`, but we will not do so.  To do so would be to sell out the thing we truly love, science.

Comment: I agree with Frank.  You need a deeper understanding of the procedures you are using.  You need to understand why p-values are invalidated by stepwise selection.  There are many, many explanations of this in the history of this site.  There is no simple fix, and there is no recipe for correct science.  Only a deeper understanding will help you.

Comment: Honestly, if you are having trouble dredging for p-values meeting an arbitrary threshold, it seems likely that the scientifically honest conclusion is that your desired research result is probably false.

Comment: so i can use what in place of stepwise or what comments i should put for these p-values ? 
other things to add are
that i am searching the influence of quantitative variables in a qualitative variable which is (normal/abnormal) this is why i am using logistic regression and stepwise selection !

Comment: Perhaps the OP would like to look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection which is one of the 'many, many explanations'

Comment: i should may be add the detail that when i did this code `glm(y~.,data=mydat,family="binomial")` i got this message 
 glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
and when i did summary of the result all the variables where significants means p-values were < 0.05 then after doing stepwise none of the selected variable is significant !

Comment: did this influence results ?

Comment: did the lrtest() solve the problem ?

Comment: Just to point this out a p<0.05 threshold does certainly not guarantee that at most 5% of research findings are false positives. I guarantees that at most 5% of p-values will be <0.05 under the null hypothesis, but depending on how many of the investigated null hypotheses hold the false positive rate could be way higher than 5%.

Comment: Fair point @Björn, my classical hypothesis testing is weak.  If you'd like to edit for more truthfulness I would appreciate it.

Comment: @prep i dont know what you mean "solve the problem". Lack of signifigance is not in itself a problem.

Comment: so what mtthew i will not have a model if all variables are not significative ! ?

Comment: You still have a model if all the variables is not significant.  It only means that, in that model, the contribution of each individual predictor is not distinguishable from noise.  The overall model may still be predictive.  If your goal is to answer a research question such as "this variable has a statistically significant effect on this thing", then, indeed, you have not proven that to be the case.

Comment: good morning , but what surprise me is that all variables were significant before stepwise selection ! what can i conclude from this result should i keep the first model or the model after selection ?

Comment: any response please i said that i have 50 variables in first step i did the following glm(y~all variables,family=binomial,data=mydat)
then summary and all the 50 variables were significative then i did stepwise it selected only 27 variables from 50 but all were not significative 
what is the conclusion then for example in case one variable x were significative and after stepwise non significative i will say x influence the qualitative  y or not ? thanks in advance

Comment: @prep is the full model what gave you the error message: "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred"?

Comment: @MatthewDrury yes the full model gave me this message 
and the model with stepwise also gave me 50 warnings the algorithm did nit converge and fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
thanks a lot for any help

Comment: what should i do please ?

Comment: Given your error messages, everything reported from your regression is not usable.  Please look up "perfect separation" on the site, this is probably what is causing your convergence/identification issues.

Comment: @matthew i looked to the posts but did not know the cause in fact in addition i did confusion matrix for both model for the first the full one accuracy was equal to 0.99  end then with the stepwise model containing non significative variables the accuracy was equal to 1
what can i conclude or correct  please ?

Comment: @prep We're at the point in this conversation where you should ask a separate question.  Please post as much detail as you can, including data, code, and a complete description of your intent.

Answer (score 5):

Without penalizing for the variable selection algorithm your results are very likely to be overstated, misleading, and P-values will be too low and confidence intervals too narrow.

Comment: hi frank,
i don't undersand what shall i do ?

Comment: Avoid stepwise regression until you understand all the ramifications of data dredging.  My course notes go into some detail: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms

Comment: but the use is a must for me ! how can i get 0.05 p values means significant variables using stepwise ? thank you in advance

Comment: Learning any field takes time.  I would not try to be an expert in your field with a few minutes of study.

Comment: yes i know that it takes time , but, i need a solution for my problem what is the meaning of "penalizing for the variable selection algorithm " ?

Comment: E.g. using penalized maximum likelihood estimation such as lasso or elastic net.

Comment: How can the use of stepwise regression be "a must"? One usually starts with a question to be investigated and then identifies an appropriate statistical method. Starting with a method (that also happens to be inappropriate for any other purpose than somehow generating p<0.05 no matter whether it means anything) is the wrong way around.